# Get players to actually role-play

Tags: system-agnostic, roleplaying

We are a bunch of newbies, have just completed our first campaign and are one evening into the second campaign.
It is now that I noticed that despite playing **role-playing games**, almost no one is exactly **role playing**.
Instead, we (including me) are all metagaming, and this seems more like a round of *stratego* or *risk* where everyone is in one team.
We have talked about this and everyone wants to role-play, but we find it hard to stay in character.

**What is the best way to get players to actually role-play their hero both in-game and outside the game?** Or is this something that will solely come with experience?