# How do I get my friends to get into character?

Tags: dnd-5e, problem-players

One of my friends is being really silly at the table. Although it gives us all a laugh, it really doesn't fit with his character or even the game I and my other buddies are trying to play. Does anyone have any experience with a player such as this or any recommended courses of action?

Comment: [Related] (Possible duple) https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/96502/43856 ; https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/45953/43856

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se. When you have time, please take our [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour). As it is, your question seems too broad, probably because it doesn't give enough details of the problem or context. We look for solving specific problems, so it helps us if you can specify what exactly is happening in your table and why is it a problem. For related questions that might help you either in solving your problem or better describing it, take a look at [tag:roleplaying].

Comment: Is this about a particular RPG system? In any case, as @HellSaint points out, your question is too broad in its current form.

Comment: If you add more details, stating the exact stuff people do out of character (according to your own perception), we might be able to help you. Without that, however, any advice is more or less pointless.

Comment: We still need a lot more details about this before it can even begin to be answered. For example, what characters are you trying to play? What is this person's character and how is this humor out of character for them? What actual issue is this causing at the table?

Comment: @Software_Programineer Do not answer in the comments. When/if the question is reopened you should consider putting it in an answer. Comments are only for suggesting improvements to the question. So save your work and put it in an answer later! See [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments) for more info. Thanks! :)

Comment: Is it too broad? What's broad about it? How to get players into character is rather straight forward to me. Asking for an experienced course of action seems straight forward too. Why is this too broad?

Comment: @Software_Programineer See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your first comment was removed. Thanks!

Comment: @Software_Programineer briefly, IMO there is not enough detail here to zero in on what issues are keeping the play from being in character or even the details of what being "in-character" mean for this table. Without those details, there is no way to narrow down advice. And giving advice about staying character in general is way too broad of a topic to get good, votable answers. If you think that it should be reopened though I suggest posting a Question in [meta].